# UITableViewCell with prepareForReuse does not work

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` where I add a bunch of buttons loaded dynamically to its `contentView`. These display properly.

When the data which controls what buttons are loaded change and I call `reloadData` I can see that `prepareForReuse` is called:

```
- (void) prepareForReuse {
    NSLog(@"prep for reuse");
    [self clearButtons];
}

- (void) clearButtons {
    NSLog(@"clearButtons called");
    self.buttons;
    for (UIView* v in buttons) {
        NSLog(@"clearing a button.");
        [v removeFromSuperview];
        [v dealloc];
    }
    buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

The buttons are not removed from the superview though, the "clearing a button." message is never logged.

I then added an explicit call to `clearButtons` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

[cell clearButtons];
```

And this time I can see that "clearing a button." is logged and everything displays correctly.

What gives? Why aren't the buttons removed when called from prepareForReuse?

Comment: I sub-class my cell, and the prepareForReuse works well. I think the problem may be at the method -clearButtons.

Answer (score 4):

You must specify a reuse identifier when the cell is created or UITableView will not call your 'prepareForReuse' method.

Per documentation, you must also call [super prepareForReuse];

Answer (score 1):

It might not related, but there are few things you should fix in createButtons:

1. Use `[v release]` instead of `[v dealloc]`
2. Release the `buttons` as well before init new one.

I would also ask that if you remove everything but NSLog, does it works?